# iOS: NSUserDefaults during the first-run-application?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using the NSUserDefaults Class to store some data but I have a normal conflict concerning the initialization.

I mean:

In my Class A in the didViewLoad method, I have set my NSUserDefaults data and afterwards in my Class B, in the didViewLoad, I want to get my NSUserDefaults data.

I have seen with the breakpoints that during the first-run-application, all the didViewLoad() of the application are performed, so I would like to put a condition in the viewDidLoad() of my Class B for the first-run-application to avoid random data initialization.

Have we got a keyword in Objective-C's framework instead of using static variable ?

eg:

ClassA--> didViewLoad():

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:kdataText forKey:@"udVariable"];

ClassB-> didViewLoad():
```

And:

ClassB--> didViewLoad():

```
if (!first_run){ // first_run --> KEYWORD FRAMEWORK???
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *var = [defaults objectForKey:@"udVariable"];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key is to call `registerDefaults` even earlier, like in `main` or in the app delegate's `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`. From an app of mine:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:
    @{@"cardMatrixRows":@4, @"cardMatrixColumns":@3}];
```

Now there is a default default, as it were, and the order of events / view controllers no longer matters.

Comment: as an addition to this answer, register defaults will register any new unregisterd values for every new build of your application, so feel free to just drop in new values in there

Comment: @matt, oh nice statements Matt! It will be very useful for my next steps :). But this statements not really fix my issue, because I need an explicit condition as:

if(First_Run)
{
//nothing
}
else{
// get data from NSUserDefault
}

I really need the if condition to perform correctly my algorithm.

Comment: @matt, I think that I have catched what you said. I have read more about [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults but I am always waiting more pragmatic information. Many thx

Comment: I'm sorry, your algorithm makes no sense to me. If you literally do *nothing* on the first run, then how will the data ever get *into* the defaults?

Comment: What I'm saying is, `register` works only if there is NO value there already. That means this *is* the first run, because you register up front and then later, if you see the first run value in the defaults, you change it.

Comment: @matt, my issue is solved. I used NSUserDefault Class. Thx you again.

Answer (score 1):

## Swift 4:

Add this code to AppDelegate within didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

`UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: ["cardMatrixRows": NSNumber(value: 4), "cardMatrixColumns": NSNumber(value: 3)])`

Answer (score 0):

Just check if 

`[defaults objectForKey:@"udVariable"] != nil`

You can also use macro #define.

Comment: Thank you, but this not fix the issue. When the user run the application and afterwards close the application and open it, the NSUserDefaults data are not reseted immediately. :/

Comment: @SAPDEV you can call [defaults synchronize] after making some changes

Comment: Thank you Andrew ... I have found that:

"he purpose of [default synchronize]; is to make the user defaults get written on disk immediately. You don't need to call it explicitly, iOS already does it at appropriate moments (like when going into background). So you can remove that line. In fact, it's a performance problem if you call synchronize every time you set a default."(DarkDust)
Basicly, I really need to code the "IF" condition to follow my algorithm correctly.