# How to iterate NSString in Swift?

Tags: ios, loops, swift, nsstring, nsarray

```
    var defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults();
    var titlesForTip : [NSString]? = defaults.objectForKey("titleForTipSegment") as? [NSString]
    if titlesForTip == nil     //Check for first run of app
    {
        titlesForTip = ["18%", "20%", "22%"]; //Default value
    }
    // it is ok to get first and last elements
    println( titlesForTip?.first) 

    for item in titlesForTip {//**error [NSString]? does not have a member named Generator**
        println(item)
    }
    //**error type  [NSString]? does not conform to protocol sequence type**
    for (var index, var value) in enumerate(titlesForTip) {
        println("Item \(index + 1): \(value)")
    }

    titlesForTip[1];//**error [NSString]? does not have a member named subscript**
```

in Debug window it shows titlesForTip including 3 elements and show in titlesForTip[0]... titlesForTip[2], but I can not visit it with [].

it is running in Xcode 6.1.1, I do not know how to iterate with it.

An error on my code:
                var titlesForTip : [NSString]? = defaults.objectForKey("titleForTipSegment") as? [NSString]
        if (titlesForTip? == nil ||  titlesForTip! == [])  //Check for first run of app
        {
            titlesForTip = ["18%", "20%", "22%"] //Default value
        }
objectForKey will return null array when there are nothing, so titlesForTip ==nil will never occur.

Comment: titlesForTip is an optional. You need to unwrap it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've created `titlesForTip` as an optional that may contain an array of `NSStrings`. Therefore, you need to check if it contains anything by unwrapping it before you can access its elements, or iterate on it.

Use code similar to this:

```
var defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
var titlesForTip : [NSString]? = defaults.objectForKey("titleForTipSegment") as? [NSString]
if titlesForTip == nil     //Check for first run of app
{
    titlesForTip = ["18%", "20%", "22%"] //Default value
}

if let unwrappedTitlesForTip = titlesForTip {
    // it is ok to get first and last elements
    println( unwrappedTitlesForTip.first) 

    for item in unwrappedTitlesForTip {
        println(item)
    }

    for (var index, var value) in enumerate(unwrappedTitlesForTip) {
        println("Item \(index + 1): \(value)")
    }

    unwrappedTitlesForTip[1] // need to do something with this, won't work just on a line on its own
}
```

Alternatively, you could set it so you don't use an optional, by setting the default value first, and overriding it if you get something from the NSDefaults, like this:

```
var defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
var titlesForTip : [NSString] = ["18%", "20%", "22%"]
if let storedValue = defaults.objectForKey("titleForTipSegment") as? [NSString] {
    titlesForTip = storedValue
}

// it is ok to get first and last elements
println( titlesForTip.first) 

for item in titlesForTip {
    println(item)
}

for (var index, var value) in enumerate(titlesForTip) {
    println("Item \(index + 1): \(value)")
}

titlesForTip[1] // need to do something with this, won't work just on a line on its own
```

Comment: Thanks, That great.In C/C++ world if ( a=b) always produce true, I do not know why swift work in this way, though it added a let in front of a=b.

Comment: Swift's `if let a = b` pattern is a way of combining a test of an optional for nil, and unwrapping the value inside that optional (if there is one) at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

As you've been told, it's merely because your array is wrapped in Optional - because *you* wrapped it in an Optional by using the `as?` operator. That's okay to do, and is a wise idea because it's safe. But then you must unwrap it:

```
var titlesForTip : [NSString]? // "wrap me in an Optional"
titlesForTip = ["18%", "20%", "22%"]
for item in titlesForTip! { // "unwrap me"
    println(item)
}
```

In your actual code, what I would do is use a conditional binding to unwrap:

```
var titlesForTip : [NSString]? = 
    defaults.objectForKey("titleForTipSegment") as? [NSString]
if let titlesForTip = titlesForTip { "unwrap me safely"
    // ...here, titlesForTip is unwrapped and safe to use...
}
```

However, in actual fact there is no need for any of that code, because there is no need to check for nil and supply a default value. Instead, call `registerDefaults:` - that's what it's for. That way, `objectForKey("titleForTipSegment")` will *always* have an `[NSString]` value and you can just cast unconditionally.

Comment: Thanks, I finished it in this way, will it be safe?          titlesForTip = defaults.objectForKey("titleForTipSegment") as? NSMutableArray
        if (titlesForTip? == nil || titlesForTip! == [] )    //Check for first run of app
        {
            titlesForTip = [0.18, 0.20, 0.22];
        }

Comment: I suppose so, but that is not the ideal way to supply a default for the first run. Call `registerDefaults:`; that's what it's for. That way, there will _always_ be an object for this key and you won't have to check for nil at all. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15991061/341994

Comment: Added mention of `registerDefaults:` to my answer.